# multiple level arguments processing with `optparse`

Tags: python

What I mean by multiple level arguments is something like `svn help`, after parsing the `svn help` part, the following word is considered argument to `help` the subcommand.

Is it possible to set this up with `optparse`?

Comment: I'd like to still see an optparse answer as well, since I'm stuck using optparse with django.  But +1 for using optparse when you have that choice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), optparse is now considered as deprecated, and won't be developed further; therefore i would strongly suggest you to use the module [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html), whith which you can create "multiple level" arguments.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Init sub-command
parser_init = subparsers.add_parser('init', help='initialize the things')
parser_init.add_argument(...)

# Help sub-command
parser_help = subparsers.add_parser('help', help='help me!')
parser_help.add_argument(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

[argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) support sub-commands : http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands
optparse is deprecated in favor of argparse since python 2.7